why get INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR when using API to get service resources
I am using API to get service resource. the full documentation can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_ls_getappointmentcandidates.htm
I am using curl to test it.
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v60.0/scheduling/getAppointmentCandidates -H 'Authorization: Bearer my_token' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"territoryIds": ["0HhQE0000000lpl0AE"], "workTypeGroupId": "0VSQE0000000HAX4A2"}'
I got result:
[{"errorCode":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"An unexpected error occurred. 
  Try again later."}]

does any one know how to solve it?
thanks
